# WinDBG - Unable to load image xx Win32 error 0n2

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-runtime, windbg

I have three crash dumps for my C# app from the Windows 8 Store Dashboard and am trying to get to the data within.

I've opened the dump in WinDBG, set the symbol path (including the MS remote server) and it is downloading most of them, but all three crash dumps fail. I'm completely new to WinDBG and this sort of debugging, but I've spent a few days hunting around and can't seem to find a solution.

The errors I get when analyzing for the dumps are as follows:

**STOWED_EXCEPTION_80004003_clr.dll!SetupErrorInfo**

```
Unable to load image mscorlib.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
Unable to load image Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
Unable to load image mscoreei.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for mscoreei.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for mscoreei.dll
Unable to load image System.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
```

**CLR_EXCEPTION_NEWTONSOFT.JSON.JSONREADEREXCEPTION...** (obvious what that is, but more info would be nice)

```
Unable to load image mscorlib.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
Unable to load image System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Windows.UI.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Windows.UI.ni.dll
Unable to load image Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MyApp.ni.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MyApp.ni.exe
Unable to load image mscoreei.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for mscoreei.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for mscoreei.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
```

**CLR_EXCEPTION_SYSTEM.ARGUMENTEXCEPTION...**

```
Unable to load image mscorlib.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
Unable to load image System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
Unable to load image mscoreei.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for mscoreei.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for mscoreei.dll
Unable to load image System.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
```

Comment: Do you have the symbols setup? Did you happen to see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15909862/95190

Comment: win32 error 0n2 - The system cannot find the file specified.
Do you have .NET Runtime installed ?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I did, but the conclusion seemed to be that NI problems with a Store app means you're pretty much out of lock - you can find out what the exception is, but not where it happens. I might just have to include better error reporting in the next app release.

Comment: @pykdteam Yeah, I'm doing this testing on my development machine, full .NET (and WinDBG grabs all the MS symbols it can't find from an MS server if you tell it to anyway).